# find command to redirect output to text, but nothing works in this case

Tags: linux, shell

seems like this should work, all the other examples I found seem to indicate that it will but it does not.

It's a short little script to find all the error_log files over 1gb in size. Works fine like this, to print to the shell window:

```
find /home -type f -name error_log -size +1048576k
```

But when I try it with this:

```
find /home -type f -name error_log -size +1048576k > output.txt
```

... I get nothing.

Of course I've tested this searching for much smaller files, which there should be plenty on the server, like this:

```
find /home -type f -name error_log -size +50k > output.txt
```

... still nothing.

Also tried:

```
find /home -type f -name error_log -size +50k >> output.txt

find /home -type f -name error_log -size +50k -print > output.txt
```

.. and so on, but without luck.

Update:

I've continued to try just about everything to get this to work. My latest attempt, this gets me plenty, that is, written out to the shell window:

find /home -type f -size +100k -name error_log -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print }'

This however, gets me nothing but a blank .txt file:

find /home -type f -size +100k -name error_log -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print > "zzzoutput.txt" }'

The above should work, right?

Comment: are you sure that the output of the command is not being written to `output.txt` in your current working dir?

Answer (score 1):

-name error_log means find all file with name error_log exactly.
However, I guess your log file may have pattern like error_log.1 error_log.2, etc, which can not be matched by -name error_log.

Comment: No actually they are all just named error_log, but they are in different account directories. As it is, what outputs to the shell window are items like this:<br/><br/>

> /home/username/public_html/directory/php_users/htdocs/error_log<br/>
> /home/username2/public_html/error_log<br/>
> /home/username3/public_html/subdirectory/error_log<br/>

So all I am trying to do is get these entries into a txt file.<br/>

Comment: NOTE: I apologize for the bad scramble in my response, I tried a number of things to format my response including those line break tags above, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Apparently it's the -size option that is preventing the results to be written to a text file. When I remove this, everything is written fine.